# What are the products of the reaction of NH4Br (aq) + Hg2(NO3)2 (aq)?

Tags: solubility

Predict the products of the following reaction based upon solubility rules. (Separate substances in a list with a comma. Include states-of-matter under the given conditions in your answer). The reaction is:

$$\ce{NH4Br (aq) + Hg2(NO3)2 (aq) -> ?}$$

I can not figure out what the products of this reaction are. I would think $\ce{NH4(NO3)(aq)}$, $\ce{Hg2Br2(aq)}$, but this is not correct.

Comment: According to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table#M), Mercury (I) salts are somewhat insoluble, so $\ce{Hg2Br2 (s)}$ would be precipitated as a solid.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table#M), mercury (I) bromide ($\ce{Hg_2Br_2}$) is somewhat insoluble (among other mercury (I) salts), so it gets precipitated as $\ce{Hg_2Br_2(s)}$ instead of $\ce{Hg_2Br_2(aq)}$, making the overall equation this:

$$\ce{2NH4Br(aq) + Hg2(NO3)2(aq) -> 2NH4NO3(aq) + Hg2Br2(s)}$$

---

Mercury (I) ions are insoluble because every orbital is full, making it unable to form ligands with water.